# Rich text in form pre-help?

Tags: html

I'm putting together a terms agreement using custom data, as a part of a new member signup profile.  I have a single required checkbox to agree, but I'd like to put the content of the terms in the from pre-help area.  Is it possible to put HTML here?  It's a huge mess as plaintext.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can paste HTML in but guessing you tried that before asking so perhaps there is something else happening on your site. Here is a [link](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/custom/group?action=preview&reset=1&id=5) to a field on demo where i just used  to prove case.

Comment: Nope just working too late,  :-P  I was pasting rich text from a doc, which does happen to work with a drupal wysiwyg.  But HTML works fine.  -Thanks